# Time Complexity (Terminated due to timeout 2s at Hackerrank)

Tags: c

**Suggest some ways to reduce the time complexity of this following code.**

The problem is:

[This is question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Epi.png)
[This is sample input output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7xMt.png)
This code is working fine except two cases (terminated due to time limit 2s)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
    {
        unsigned char str[1000000];
        unsigned long int l;
        int i,j,t,k,c=0;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        for(k=0;k<t;k++)
        {
            c=0;
            scanf("%lu",&l);
            scanf("%s",str);
            for(i=0;i<l-1;i++)
            {
                for(j=i+1;j<l;j++)
                    if(str[i]=='S' && str[j]=='A')
                        c++;
            }
            printf("%d\n",c);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  Pleae provide more informaion on the two cases. What is the input, what is special in contrast to the other cases?

Comment: You are supposed to do the challenge yourself, otherwise there's no point in doing it. Also please don't post images of text, links, or links to images of text where text is called for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the following algorithm to solve:
Traverse the string :
a variable count which will store number of S's before a currently found A and total which is the total substrings found yet.

```
int total=0,count=0;
for(int j=0; j < s.length(); ++j){ //s.length or till wherever you want to find
    if(s[j] == 'A') total+=count;
    else if(s[j]=='S')  count++;
}
```